# exclude constraints in pgmodeler

Tags: pgmodeler

I want to add an exclusion constraint to a table in pgmodeler.

Example table:

```
create table x (
   lable varchar(2) not null,
   timerange tstzrange not null,
   primary key (lable, timerange))
);
```

And I want to add:

```
alter table x add constraint ex_x_overlap
exclude using gist(lable with =, timerange with &&);
```

What I tried in pgmodeler

- open table properties
- chose constraints
- add constraint
- choose a name
- chose type "EXCLUDE"
- add first exclude element, column "lable", **but no operator available**

My problem is that the operator field is mandatory, but not free text. I need to select an operator form one of the schemas. However "=" is not there (there are none in fact...).

I think I misunderstand something, any help appreciated!

Comment: Found answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

## Exclusion Constraints in Pgmodeler..

Refer : https://m-thirumal.github.io/installation_guide/#/pgmodeler/Exclusion%20Constraints

1. Create Extension
2. Create dummy function
3. Create dummy operator
4. Add constraint to table

#### Create Dummy Function:

1. Click on `Objects` -> `projects` -> `schema` -> `pg_catalog` -> `function` -> `Create function` with parameterm & return type

```
<function name="dummy_func" sql-disabled="true"
        window-func="false"
        returns-setof="false"
        behavior-type="CALLED ON NULL INPUT"
        function-type="VOLATILE"
        security-type="SECURITY INVOKER"
        parallel-type="PARALLEL UNSAFE"
        execution-cost="1"
        row-amount="0">
    <schema name="pg_catalog"/>
    <role name="postgres"/>
    <language name="sql"/>
    <return-type>
    <type name="bigint" length="0"/>
    </return-type>
    <transform-types names="bigint"/>
    <parameter name="p1">
        <type name="bigint" length="0"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p2">
        <type name="bigint" length="0"/>
    </parameter>
    <definition> <![CDATA[null]]> </definition>
</function>
```

!> After creating function `disable SQL`

#### Create Dummy Operator:

1. Click on `Objects` -> `projects` -> `schema` -> `pg_catalog` -> `function` -> `Create Operator`

```
<operator name="=" sql-disabled="true">
    <schema name="pg_catalog"/>
    <role name="postgres"/>
    <type name="bigint" length="0" ref-type="left-type"/>
    <type name="bigint" length="0" ref-type="right-type"/>
    <function ref-type="operfunc" signature="pg_catalog.dummy_func(bigint,bigint)"/>
</operator>
```

!> After creating function `disable SQL`

#### Adding it to table

`Open Table` -> `Constraint` -> `Create new Constraints` ->  Select `Exclude Constraints` -> select the column

```
<table name="party_relationship" layers="0" collapse-mode="2" max-obj-count="18" z-value="0">
    <schema name="icms"/>
    <role name="postgres"/>
    <position x="1580" y="2220"/>
    <column name="party_relationship_id" not-null="true">
        <type name="bigserial" length="0"/>
    </column>
    <column name="contemporaneous" not-null="true" default-value="''::hstore">
        <type name="public.hstore" length="0"/>
        <comment> <![CDATA[What is the identification, name, address, email and phone number is used at the time of case. PK of these tables will be stored along with table name]]> </comment>
    </column>
    <column name="start_time" not-null="true" default-value="current_timestamp">
        <type name="timestamptz" length="0"/>
    </column>
    <column name="end_time" not-null="true" default-value="'infinity'::timestamp">
        <type name="timestamptz" length="0"/>
    </column>
    <column name="description">
        <type name="varchar" length="500"/>
        <comment> <![CDATA[Any additional Information]]> </comment>
    </column>
    <column name="row_created_on" not-null="true" default-value="current_timestamp">
        <type name="timestamptz" length="0"/>
    </column>
    <column name="row_updated_on" not-null="true" default-value="current_timestamp">
        <type name="timestamptz" length="0"/>
    </column>
    <column name="row_update_info">
        <type name="varchar" length="200"/>
    </column>
    <constraint name="party_relationship_pk" type="pk-constr" table="icms.party_relationship">
        <columns names="party_relationship_id" ref-type="src-columns"/>
    </constraint>

    <customidxs object-type="column">
        <object name="icms_case_id" index="2"/>
        <object name="l_party_id" index="3"/>
        <object name="parent_party_relationship_id" index="1"/>
        <object name="r_party_id" index="4"/>
        <object name="relationship_cd" index="5"/>
        <object name="row_created_by" index="11"/>
        <object name="row_updated_by" index="13"/>
    </customidxs>
    <customidxs object-type="constraint">
        <object name="icms_case_fk" index="4"/>
        <object name="l_party_fk" index="3"/>
        <object name="party_fk" index="6"/>
        <object name="party_fk1" index="7"/>
        <object name="party_relationship_fk" index="5"/>
        <object name="r_party_fk" index="2"/>
        <object name="relationship_cd_fk" index="1"/>
    </customidxs></table>
```

#### For Diff

On `Import & Export` -> check `Import System Objects` & `Import extension objects`